# How should I construct my tic-tac-toe server using SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, unity-game-engine

This is my first post on StackOverflow. I apologize that my question is almost open-ended. But I'm working on a full-stack app for Tic-Tac-Toe.

I want to make it to where two players can create a room to play with one another. To do this I want to make a small database using SQL so that data can be stored, this is also for a project. My goal, for now, is to make this app playable through Postman. I want the client to be responsible for creating a game instance, which would end up being a URL with a unique 'roomId' at the end of it. I'm having trouble creating the tables which would store that data. I'm still at square one essentially.

What I'm having trouble with currently is creating the row which would store the 3 x 3 board. I've tried making a separate table that would store what is basically just an array. The entries are squareOne, squareTwo, etc. I don't know if this is correct because I'm not sure how I would set it up to where the client knows which specific square it's going to be updating. I know that the client would likely be responding with an index and a player id, so it would look something like

```
...com/game/:roomId/:playerId/:index
```

Here are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE board 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    squareOne INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareTwo INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareThree INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareFour INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareFive INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareSix INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareSeven INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareEight INTEGER NOT NULL,
    squareNine INTEGER NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE game 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    date_ended TIMESTAMP,
    player_started_id INTEGER,
    player_joined_id INTEGER,
    board ??? I don't know what should go here
);
```

What I want this server to do is ultimately be able to handle multiple games running at once. So each time a game is created a new entry is made on the game table and the URL that responds with that unique ID is referencing the id of the game table id.

Please let me know where I can improve, and how to properly set these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll prefer to store the player choices instead of the all board. Your board table represent your full business object. You could try a table like : GAME_ID, PLAYER_ID, SQUARE_X, SQUARE_Y (X and Y represent the position on the board). You can make a composite Primary key with GAME_ID, SQUARE_X, SQUARE_Y to ensure that only one player can be on a square. With this rows you can rebuild your "BOARD" game business object.

Even your actual model could handle multiple games, but you never talk about the technology used to serve API. (ASP.net ? node.js ? )

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think that's a great idea actually. It helps remove unnecessary logic. I will try to implement. I'm using node.js, i can share a link to the code. https://github.com/hernandez-crypto/tic-tac-toe-capstone .